# Solaris how to exclude files in gz

Tags: solaris, tar

How do I exclude files while gz in Solaris;
I want to gz directories inc sub directories but exclude /temp directory and *.gz files.
This is what I have used so far;

```
tar -cvf api_v2.x.tar.gz --exclude *.gz --exclude ./temp api
```

which still including the excluding folders.

Answer (score 2):

The Solaris `tar` command features the `X` switch to exclude files/directories. Please see the man page `man tar` for usage.

From the man page:

> X
>
> ```
> Exclude.  Use the exclude-file argument as a file containing a list
> of relative path names for files (or directories)  to  be  excluded
> from the tarfile when using the functions c, x, or t. Be careful of
> trailing white spaces. Also beware of leading white spaces,  since,
> for each line in the excluded file, the entire line (apart from the
> newline) is used to match against the initial string  of  files  to
> exclude. Lines in the exclude file are matched exactly, so an entry
> like "/var" does not exclude the /var directory if tar  is  backing
> up  relative  pathnames.  The entry should read "./var" under these
> circumstances. The tar command does not expand shell metacharacters
> in the exclude file, so specifying entries like "*.o" does not have
> the effect of excluding all files with names suffixed with ".o". If
> a  complex list of files is to be excluded, the exclude file should
> be generated by some means such as the find(1) command with  appro-
> priate conditions.
>
> Multiple  X  arguments can be used, with one exclude-file per argu-
> ment. In the case where included files (see -I  include-file  oper-
> and)  are  also  specified, the excluded files take precedence over
> all included files. If a file is specified in both the exclude-file
> and the include-file (or on the command line), it is excluded.
> ```

Note the last sentence of the first paragraph stating:

If a  complex list of files is to be excluded, the exclude file should
be generated by some means such as the find(1) command with  appro-
priate conditions.

On recent Solaris versions there is also the GNU tar which can be used as `gtar` with the corresponding man page at `man gtar`. This version features the `--exclude=PATTERN`

**Examples**

Example using `tar`:

```
/tmp$ find api/
api/
api/a.gz
api/temp
api/temp/b
api/b

/tmp$ cat api/exclude_from_tar 
api/a.gz
api/temp

/tmp$ tar cvfX api.tar api/exclude_from_tar api
a api/ 0K
a api/a.gz excluded
a api/temp excluded
a api/exclude_from_tar 1K
a api/b 0K

/tmp$ tar tf api.tar 
api/
api/exclude_from_tar
api/b
```

Example using `gtar`:

```
/tmp$ gtar cvf api.tar --exclude="*.gz" --exclude=temp api
api/
api/exclude_from_tar
api/b

/tmp$ tar tf api.tar 
api/
api/exclude_from_tar
api/b
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this is the closest that I came up with but still dont work :(

   `tar -cvfXX api_v2.x.tar.gz  *.gz  ./temp api`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the `*.gz` pattern (`"*.gz"`) if the current directory contains .gz files, otherwise the shell will expand the pattern before tar sees it.

You will also need to add `z` to the argument list if you want tar to produce a gzipped archive.

Comment: The `z` argument does not exist in `tar` on Solaris. To create a gzipped archive use `tar cf - source | gzip -c > source.tar.gz` or `gtar -z`

Comment: The `z` argument exists in `tar` on Solaris 11, since 2011.  It does not exist on Solaris 10 and older.